# Two blank users showing up on network-wide mod listing

Tags: bug, moderators, stackexchange.com

I just took a glance at the [list of moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users) on the network, and noticed something... odd:

[image]

There are two blank profiles showing up there - but the avatars remain. They appear to be [Steven Jeuris](https://stackexchange.com/users/289676/steven-jeuris) and [Jeromy Anglim](https://stackexchange.com/users/60581/jeromy-anglim) - who had been moderators on the now-defunct Startups.SE.

(Interestingly, Jeromy is still a mod on [Psychology.SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/users/52/jeromy-anglim), but isn't showing up on there. [Matthew Haugen](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/10011/matthew-haugen), the other ex-Startups.SE mod, who's a mod on Ask Patents, is still showing up there.)

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: The answer to "should I blame caching?" in this case is a resounding "hell yes". This will *technically* fix itself eventually. In practice, I would purge the cache key that keeps hold of the mod info... but my ability to do that is also broken at the moment. Should be fixed up tomorrow, so I'll give it a go then to try and force an update here.

Comment: And a few hours later... it fixed itself after all. :) Isn't caching wonderful?